# Select hardcoded values without table

Tags: postgresql

I need to run a select without actually connecting to any table. I just have a predefined hardcoded set of values I need to loop over:

```
foo
bar
fooBar
```

And I want to loop through those values. I can do:

```
select 'foo', 'bar', 'fooBar';
```

But this returns it as one row:

```
 ?column? | ?column? | ?column? 
----------+----------+----------
 foo      | bar      | fooBar
(1 row)
```

I am using Postgresql.

Answer (score 187, accepted):

```
select a
from (
    values ('foo'), ('bar'), ('fooBar')
) s(a);
```

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-values.html

Comment: It is possible to write "AS s(a)" instead of "s(a)" which makes it more explicit that "s(a)" gives names to the hardcoded table, where the "a" is the column name.

Comment: @peschü - worked when I tried it.

Comment: Worked nicely, but what _is_ `s` here exactly and why does it know how to return the value instead of a tuple??

Comment: @MatheusFelipe `s` is the table name and `a` is the column name. So you could've written `select s.a` instead too. The parenthesis (`(a)`) isn't required, but then the column name gets a default name of `column1` instead (i.e., `select s.column1`).

Answer (score 66):

To produce more than one column,

```
SELECT * 
FROM (VALUES ('Foo', 25), ('Bar', 30), ('Baz', 35)) AS t(name, age);
```

output

```
 name | age 
------+-----
 Foo  |  25
 Bar  |  30
 Baz  |  35
```

---

Using [`unnest()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-array.html)

> Expand an array to a set of rows

```
select unnest(array['foo', 'bar', 'fooBar']);
```

[demo](http://rextester.com/AZQUM38483)

To produce more than one columns

```
SELECT *
FROM unnest(
            ARRAY['foo', 'bar', 'fooBar'] 
           ,ARRAY[25, 30, 35]
           ) AS t(name, AGE);
```

output:

```
 name  | age
-------+-----
 foo   |  25
 bar   |  30
 fooBar|  35
```

Comment: This works fine when there is only one value to be unnested, but quickly becomes unreadable when multiple have to be provided as you have to separate the values in many different unnest

Comment: Most simple and complete syntax `SELECT x, 2 y  FROM unnest('{1,2,3}'::int[]) t(x);`

Comment: @Luke using my illustrated `t(x)` and `t2(x)` etc. you can use LATERAL JOIN, CROSS JOIN, INTERSECTION, etc. and express datatypes.

Answer (score 11):

**Postgres SQL:**

For static data output as single row and multiple columns representation use following query:

```
select a,b,c from (values('foo','bar','fooBar')) s(a,b,c);
```

result of this SQL query:

[image]

Comment: I don't think this is what OP is after, @Clodoaldo Neto's answer is the correct method for this syntax.