# How to use SQL WITH VALUES clause to define constant value

Tags: sql, postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have:

```
SELECT *
FROM weather_data
WHERE parameter_type = 'TEMPERATURE';
```

I want to write this as:

```
WITH ParameterType AS (VALUES ('TEMPERATURE'))
SELECT *
FROM weather_data
WHERE parameter_type = ParameterType;
```

I get error: "column "parametertype" does not exist"

Comment: Duplicate with: [Select hardcoded values without table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15948614/select-hardcoded-values-without-table) ??

Comment: @Luuk there probably is a number of similar threads including the one you linked, but I wouldn't say that one's exactly the same: the goal is opposite to that of OP's - here they *do* want a single row (and a single value).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A CTE works just like a table.

The query below is an equivalent of what you wrote and it should be obvious to you why it will **not** work (A table is not a valid operand for the `=` operator).

```sql
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Column1 = SomeOtherTable;
```

The correct approach would of course be:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Column1 = (SELECT Column1 FROM SomeOtherTable);
```

This works only if `SELECT Column1 FROM SomeOtherTable` is a scalar subquery (i.e. 1 row, 1 column). If you have more than 1 row, use the `IN` operator:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM SomeTable
WHERE Column1 IN (SELECT Column1 FROM SomeOtherTable);
```

---

Back to your query, we want to ideally name the column of your CTE, then use it as I described above:

```sql
WITH ParameterType(ParamValue) AS (VALUES ('TEMPERATURE'))
SELECT *
FROM weather_data
WHERE parameter_type IN (SELECT ParamValue FROM ParameterType);
```

Note#1: your CTE only has 1 column so naming it is optional; you could also make it work with `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT ParamValue`.
Note#2: there are, of course, other ways to achieve the same thing, such as `INNER JOIN`, `EXISTS (SELECT ...)`, etc. Such ways could be convenient for a CTE with more than 1 column.

Comment: Minor remark: a table name *is* a valid operand for `=`, [see this](https://dbfiddle.uk/LbO-tgqO). The error was caused by the missing column name in it, and once that'd be fixed, a type mismatch error would follow.

Comment: To be precise (or it is OK to call me pedantic at this level), the example you posted does not demonstrate a comparison between 2 tables but rather between **records** of the 2 tables, which is different (this is easily shown by running a query such as `WITH a(x,y) AS (VALUES(1,1),(2,2)) SELECT a from a WHERE a = ROW(1,1)`, especially in a SQL client that shows column types: `SELECT a` returns 1 column of type `record` and `a = ROW(1,1)` clearly is a record-level comparison but not a table-level comparison.

Comment: Also, this all works because in your example, you added table `a` in the `FROM` clause, which was not the case in the question. The precise usage of this syntax is described [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/rowtypes.html#ROWTYPES-USAGE); quote (highlight is from me): "*In PostgreSQL, a reference to a table name (or alias) in a query is effectively a reference to the composite value of the table's **current row**.*". Conclusion: you should not mix rows with the table they are coming from (even though they have the same name) and I consider that part of my answer valid.

Comment: The difference is between me talking about **tables** not being valid operands (which they are not) and you talking about **table names** (which are in fact references to records of a table, as per the quote I extracted from the documentation). Is it clear if I put it this way? The devil is in the details...

Comment: While they are valid, I also consider answers where the provided code can only execute in the database tagged in the question to be inferior to answers that fully comply with ANSI SQL. Using records is definitely one of these cases.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the `cte` at all: [demo at db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/W6id6BmC)

```
SELECT *
FROM weather_data,(VALUES ('TEMPERATURE'))_(ParameterType)
WHERE parameter_type = ParameterType;
```

This spawns a single-value table the same way and joins it with your table the same way.

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: there is another way to write the same, see: [docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-values.html) and https://dbfiddle.uk/lCTBinSG

Comment: `,` is not a habit here - when you're really only gluing a single value to your set, replacing `full outer join..on true` *with a single punctuation character*, is a worthwhile syntax noise saver. Still, it never hurts to underline what defaults and implicit mechanics are in place, so thanks. As to the other comment, I'm not sure if you forgot to add something to my examples in the fiddle that's already in the answer (and run to save/generate a new link), or renaming an alias from `_` to `t` is all you wanted to add.

Comment: sorry, I did not recognize the alias .... (I never used `_` as an alias, and spaces are missing which made it hard to recognize...)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to select from some values, rather than just creating a table and inserting into it, you can do something like:

```
WITH  params (v) AS (VALUES (0), (10)) 
SELECT * 
FROM params ;
```

This will outputs :

```
v
0
10
```

To join this dataset with your current table you can do something like :

```
WITH  params (v) AS (VALUES (0), (10)) 
SELECT w.* 
FROM weather_data w
INNER JOIN params p on w.parameter_type = p.v
```

Answer (score 0):

With clause is used to define named result sets or CTEs.
In your case, the ParameterType is not accessible in the where clause.

Try something like this.

```
WITH weatherData AS (
  SELECT *
  FROM weather_data
  WHERE parameter_type = 'TEMPERATURE'
)
SELECT *
FROM weatherData
```